# PostgreSQL - SSL connection without providing the root-ca certificate?

Tags: postgresql, ssl

I set the following parameters to enable SSL on my PostgreSQL server:

- ssl = True
- ssl_ca_file = 'path-to-root-ca'
- ssl_cert_file = 'path-to-server-crt'
- ssl_key_file = 'path-to-server-key'

For my tests, I use the PGSSLROOTCERT variable which contains the path to the root ca certificate.

I realized that it is still possible for a client to connect to the database without providing the root CA certificate and that the prompt states that an SSL connection is used:

```
psql "postgres://user:XXXXXX@hostname:port/postgres"
psql (10.2, server 10.3 (Debian 10.3-1.pgdg90+1))
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \q

psql "postgres://user:XXXXXX@hostname:port/postgres?sslmode=verify-ca"
psql (10.2, server 10.3 (Debian 10.3-1.pgdg90+1))
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \q
```

If the PGSSLROOTCERT variable is set to a wrong value:

```
psql "postgres://user:XXXXXX@hostname:port/postgres?sslmode=verify-ca"
psql: SSL error: certificate verify failed
```

The pg_hba.conf file:

```
local  all  postgres    trust
hostssl  all  all  0.0.0.0/0  md5
```

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of `PGSSLROOTCERT` or `sslrootcert`, the library `libpq` (which `psql` uses) looks in a compiled-in default location for the file.  And apparently, it finds it at that location.

For Linux, that location is `~/.postgresql/root.crt`.  Although it is possible that "Debian 10.3-1.pgdg90+1" patched it to look someplace else instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My client is a computer running under MacOS: there isn't such directoy as ~/.postgresql.

Comment: Ah of course, `Debian` refers to the server, not the client.  What I would do then is run something like `strace -eopen psql ...` and see what files it is actually opening.  (Although I don't know if MacOS has strace, it probably has something similar)